# How do I parse a delimited string into a slice of substrings?

Tags: parsing, go

Given a URL like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3001/find?fields=hostname,App,Node_type,invalid
```

I extract fields into a slice like this:

```
filters := r.URL.Query().Get("fields")
fmt.Println(filters)
```

Result:

```
hostname,App,Node_type,invalid
```

It is received as a string, but I'd prefer to separate the substrings into a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your URL should be

```
http://127.0.0.1:3001/find?fields=hostname&fields=App&fields=Node_type&fields=invalid
```

or if you don't like that, you can parse

```
filterSlice:=strings.Split("filters", ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

The question actually concerns how to split a string on a particular delimiter. For that, you can use [the `strings.Split()` function](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split):

```
import "strings"
// ...
filters := strings.Split(r.URL.Query().Get("fields"), ",")
```

Your `filters` variable will now be a slice, which may be empty if there was no "fields" query parameter available.

Comment: Actually previous answer was exactly what I wanted. That solved my issue. I think you misread my question. I will take blame for not clearly expressing as well.

Comment: I'm happy you figured it out, but your original question was puzzling over how to separate the "fields" values. I assumed that the URL format was not open for discussion. If you can take @Uvelichitel's advice and change the URL format, so much the better. While we're here, be forewarned that you can still wind up with duplicate "fields" values, so you may wish to collect them into a set structure to help eliminate duplicates—if that's what your application needs.